# Combine results to count totals for individuals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in my database that keeps track of pages sent to individual users and groups. Users are part of groups. Only individual users can answer pages. Here is the DDL for the table:

```
    --PageStatus 1 = Expired
    --PageStatus 2 = Answered
    --PageStatus 3 = Canceled

    CREATE TABLE [Pagings] (
    [Id] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    [UserProfileId] int NULL ,
    [GroupId] int NULL ,
    [Message] nvarchar(MAX) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL ,
    [PageStatus] int NOT NULL ,
    [DateCreated] datetime NULL ,
    [DateModified] datetime NULL ,
    [IsRecurring] bit NOT NULL DEFAULT ((0)) ,
    [AnsweredById] int NULL ,
    [AnsweredDateTime] datetime NULL ,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ft.Pagings] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
      )
    ON [PRIMARY]
    TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Anytime the `PageStatus` is `Expired` (1) or `Canceled` (3) we do not have any data for the `AnsweredById` or the `AnsweredDateTime` columns. If it is answered then we set the value of the `UserProfileId` coming from the application in the  `AnsweredById` column of the person who answered it. If a group is paged anyone who answered the page is assumed to be part of that group and their `UserProfileId` is set inside the `AnsweredById` column.

Here is a sample result and the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/170cc/1) to accompany the data.
[image]

I need to figure out how to get the Total count of pages for a User including the group they belong to, how many pages they answered, and the group totals. Here is an example of what I would expect as the result based on the set above:

```
UserId GroupId  TotalPagesForUser  TotalAnsweredForUser TotalPagesForGroup TotalAnsweredForGroup
------ -------  -----------------  -------------------- ------------------ ----------------------
1       2         3                1                     1                 1
3       1         3                1                     2                 2
4       1         2                1                     2                 2
```

I've tried joining the table to itself on the `UserProfileId` and `AnsweredById` and with a `Group` table that exists in the database, but my results were way off and i end up with a a lot of duplicated data.

Comment: Thank you for setting up a SQLFiddle! In your test data for the Fiddle, the `UserId` `4` only shows up in the `AnsweredById` column. How are we to infer what `GroupId` that user belongs to?

Comment: In order to construct the output table you are asking for, we'll need that `Group` table in the Fiddle (as well as any other information not represented in the data sample).

Comment: @SQLTactics to answer you first question, I stated above that if a group is paged the user answering it is assumed to be part of that group. I will add the group table to the fiddle.

Comment: @SQLTactics, I updated the fiddle to include the UserProfiles table and Group table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would break it into two parts, first assemble the aggregate numbers for Users, then get the Group numbers either in a subquery as part of the main query or two separate queries with the results being assembled at the end.  Anyway, my rough first attempt:

```
Select u.Id as UserId,  
g.Id as GroupId,
g.name as GroupName,
count(0) as TotalPagesForUser,
Sum(case when p.AnsweredById IS NOT NULL then 1 else 0 end) as TotalAnsweredForUser,
(SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Pagings WHERE GroupId = g.Id) as TotalPagesForGroup,
(SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Pagings WHERE GroupId = g.Id AND AnsweredById IS NOT NULL) as TotalAnsweredForGroup
from UserProfiles u
INNER JOIN Groups g on g.Id = u.GroupId
INNER JOIN Pagings p on p.UserProfileId = u.Id or p.AnsweredById = u.Id
GROUP BY u.Id, g.Id, g.name
ORDER BY u.Id
```

Although I'm getting slightly different values than what you were projecting...but I haven't had a chance to look over the source data in detail yet.

Comment: The initial numbers look good. I suppose I could Union a User query then a group query and rename the columns so they match.

Comment: I added the group totals now.